# Error starting process. Cannot create pty - Eclipse on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to run a simple C++ program on Eclipse in mac. But it is not working. I have Xcode installed and I did try setting all the Eclipse settings that people suggested online, but still I am getting no where.

The error message:

[image: Eclipse run time error]

Comment: Its a bug . Some compatibility issue between eclipse and macos high sierra. This is resolved by upgrading eclipse . Please refer below for more information. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=519886

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you update to the Oxygen.1 version of the C/C++ IDE (CDT version 9.2.2). It contains a fix for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse Neon, update to  CDT version 9.3.X by adding repo:

```
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/9.3
```

and rebuild the project before running it.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem when I updated my macOS 10.12 to 10.13 in Eclipse Oxygen.1A.
By upgrading the CDT plugin I solved the problem.